# Front and / or Rear Tires Doors or Windows testing in Aircraft

Tags: landing, tire

I would like to know before the landing takes place, is there a way out for the pilot to know whether the doors or windows for the Front and Rear tires of the Aircraft will work 100%?

If i am not wrong, the doors or windows are opened while landing for the Front and Rear tires to open.

In case the door or window which i am referring does not open, will it not be a risk for landing?

Is there a technical term for the door or window part of the aircraft which i am referring?

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is *landing gear door*.

Comment: *"is there a way out for the pilot to know whether the doors or windows for the Front and Rear tires of the Aircraft will work 100%"* Very few things in life are 100% guaranteed. There are a number of indications that can tell them it *may not* be working, but that's not to say something may happen later that isn't caught by those methods.

Comment: Sorry, but I am downvoting because it is not clear whether you are asking about landing gear door operation, testing landing gear doors, sequencing gear assemblies from up and locked to down and locked, or somehow automating the application of brakes during different phases of flight.  (per your comments)  We can help you edit the terms if we understood better what you are actually asking.  And what are the pictures intended to illustrate?

Comment: I am trying to automate the tires opening and closing for different plane motions. Plane at rest on ground, Plane in motion on ground preparing for take off, Plane in Sky after take off, Plane again on ground after landing.
I feel the Transaction from Plane in Sky to Land is difficult to automate. i e Tires closed to Tires opening for landing.
Plane at rest on ground, Plane in motion on ground will require the Tires to open and work while the Plane in Sky the tires do not be required to be open so they are in closed position. Tires open - UnLocked action, Tires closed - Locked action.

Comment: I feel the comment that was supposed to clarify the situation has only confused me more…

Comment: Thanks. I am also researching on whether Automating the function of the landing gear classify as a Machine learning or Artificial Intelligence technologies business use case in Aviation industry.

Comment: @Digital Dracula, glad I'm not the only one...  I voted to close for lack of clarity.

Comment: Oh yeah, and for those who didn't bother following our other discussion over to chat, it turns out that "rubber sensors" means tire pressure monitoring system, and that this function is also a part of the question, and under consideration for possible automation.  Whatever that might entail...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no 100% guarantees in life, certainly not in aviation. But in the interest of safety pilots have multiple indications available, and options in case things go wrong.

In most planes the landing gear and gear doors are either hydraulically or electrically operated. The hydraulic and electric systems are critical throughout the aircraft, so there are indications to the crew that can show if there are any issues with these systems. There is also usually an alternate method of extension in case the primary system has issues. Gravity typically helps.

Once the gear is extended, it gets locked in place. The crew will have an indication of whether each landing gear location is down and locked, typically with an indicator that shows red while the gear is in motion and turns green once it's locked. You can see the indicators in the image below for Nose, Left, and Right gear.

[image: Gear lever and indicators]

If there is an indication of an issue, pilots may sometimes fly a low approach to the runway without landing to let ATC look at the gear to see if everything looks normal. It's possible that the gear is down but not locked, or locked but just not indicating properly.

If there are issues, the crew must simply work their checklists to try as best they can to get the gear down, and then land carefully. Airplanes are designed to land with some or all gear up in case these issues happen. Rescue crews can be on standby to help passengers and crew evacuate in these situations.

In 2011, [a 767 had to land with its gear up](https://avherald.com/h?article=4456bd6b) after the crew was unable to get the gear to extend. The airplane was a total loss but no one on board was killed or injured.

[image: 767 gear up landing]

Comment: Thanks for the information provided. I would like to know whether the Nose (Front) & Main (Rear) Landing Gear are automatically locked or unlocked instead of Human manual intervention?. If not, do you feel this can be automated taking into consideration as Locked while plane in air (Tires not touching the ground) & Unlocked (Tires touching the ground) using sensors.https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-lava&sxsrf=ALeKk022XyFnLlMV32OAAEPYnkxLeGuwuA:1628734034281&q=rubber+sensor&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfpa-Ms6ryAhVbQH0KHYPcBQMQBSgAegQIARAC&biw=360&bih=592

Comment: What do you mean by "automated" vs "manual intervention"? There are a series of mechanical linkages and hydraulic actuators that control extension and retraction of the landing gear that begin a designed sequence when the handle is placed up or down.  Are you suggesting a system for removing the need to move a handle?

Comment: The "lock" in this case is not like a padlock with a key, and the pilots have to manually set the padlock. "Locked" means the mechanical actuators are fully in place and the safety mechanisms that prevent the gear from being pushed back up when the plane lands have properly engaged.

Comment: Thanks Michael. The Handle is there in case Human manual intervention is required for locking and unlocking the Gears.By default the Nose & Main Gear are automatically Locked or UnLocked using sensor technology. Example : Three stages of motion. 1 Before taking Acent in sky, plane on ground so Gears are Unlocked. 2 After Ascent in sky, plane not in ground so Gears are Locked. 3 Plane landing on ground so Gears are UnLocked. All the Above motions can be automated for the gears by default using rubber sensors or any other means? Note: The Handle is there in case manual intervention is required.

Comment: The handle is there to manually initiate the extension or retraction sequence.  The gear is locked into place either up or down with mechanical latches.  There is no separate manual locking operation required under normal operation.  Light indications in the cockpit are activated by simple electrical position switches.  Otherwise I'm not clear on what you are either asking, or mis-explaining...

Comment: Thanks Michael. I got your point. I was just curious to know whether the gears actions i.e. locked or unlocked positions can be automated depending on the motion whether the tires do not touch the ground (Locked - Plane On Ascent- In Sky) or touch the ground (Unlocked - Plane Before Ascent, Plane After Landing on Ground). The Handle will be always there for manual intervention for Gear locking and unlocking mechanisms. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Almost anything can be automated, but in this case, why?  Simple mechanical linkages work just fine, automation would just introduce an additional failure mode. 
 Also, your description of locked or unlocked during different phases of flight doesn't really make sense... i.e. "Unlocked... plane after landing on ground" What does this even mean?  The gear would collapse if it wasn't locked down on the ground.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I got your point. It will be difficult to build the automated logic when the plane is going to land in ground. Because the Gear has to be brought from locked to unlocked position before touching the ground. How automatically this action can be performed that i will be landing so unlock, so in this case manual intervention will be required by the pilot for unlocking? Maybe the first two motions can be automated i.e. Plane before ascent, tires touching the ground, so unlocked and Plane in Ascent, tires not touching the ground, so locked using rubber sensors technology.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who participated for answering to my queries about Aircraft Tires.

Comment: When you say locked, are you talking about the tires rotating?  Because that is different...  (I assumed you were referring to the struts and braces themselves) 
 And I don't know what you mean by "rubber sensors", but the antiskid system can sense wheel rotation and is normally programmed to send a brake release signal with weight off wheels to prevent landing with the brakes applied.  I guess in that sense it is automated... 
 Anyway, I think we may be having some language barriers that prevent clear communication.  (since the title question is more about the gear doors...)

Comment: Thanks Michael. I understood all your answers to my queries. There is no language communication barrier. I thank you and all who helped me with my queries on Aircraft tires.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128482/discussion-between-prashant-akerkar-and-michael-hall).